# Where can I find linux drivers for my PC running Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers

I have a very old HP Compaq d530 CMT that I put Ubuntu on, but there is something screwed up. I only see a desktop pic and nothing else, but I already got help for that [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/398001/dash-and-launcher-is-missing-after-installation) The Dash and launcher is still missing, so I think that I need drivers for this old PC, but I don't know what to get and I don't know what brand the GPU is, but is is onboard graphics. The motherboard is 323091-001

Comment: googling got me nowhere and same with about and going to the software updater --> additional drivers

Comment: Go to system settings --> Details. What does it say there in the graphics part.

Comment: it says the graphics is unknown

Comment: after a fast google I found this, btw is this your computer? http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?os=20&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&sw_lang=&product=316721#N374
 Of course you can't use those drivers but it tells you that it's a nvidia driver.

Comment: I tried nvidia drivers, but maybe they were too new. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will have no problem when you install Xubuntu:

http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/

Unity runs quite bad on old computers as it more resource hungry, I recommend you to install the Xubuntu version and start having no problems at all and notice a big speedup improvement.

PS: Use the 32 bit 13.10 version as you have less than 4 gigs of ram and you aren´t using a latest-gen processor.

PS 2: Try to update the BIOS of the motherboard.

Comment: that doesn't help if the drivers aren't installed. I don't use Unity and I still have this issue if I don't Install the drivers.

Comment: I can't update the BIOS without pirating windows and I have had performance issues with xubuntu, but I will try it. lubuntu and ubuntu don't work on this PC.